# How I can choose network device in socket ()?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

My plan is to write a user-based bandwidth control for Internet connection. To do this, I first want to write a network cable emulator.

My Linux box has three network devices:

- `Eth0` for normal connection to the network.
- `Eth1`  and `Eth2` are the endings of the emulated network cable.

So, what my program has to do is only to get every network packet from the input of `eth1` and put it to the output of`eth2`, and get every network packet from the input of `eth2` and put it to the output of `eth1`.

With `s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))`, I can access every network packet. Hope that `eth1`and `eth2`  are in promiscuous mode.

But, how do I choose the network device? Later, I want to differentiate on the IP source-address that is in each packet, and how long this packet must wait, before I put it to the other network device.

Comment: After you create a socket with `socket()`, you can use `bind()` or `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)` to assign a specific device to it as needed.

Comment: @stackunderflow have you looked at linux bridging? This is exactly what a bridge does, only without any userspace code.

Comment: @Malt At the moment this is exactly what a bridge does. But later my code can delay packets that fit some requirements (IP-Adress, Service, ...) So I can program quality of service eg. prevent that heavy downloads close the internet-line for realtime applications. Imagine my cable-emulator is between gateway and internetrouter of a pool of maybe 50 users. I can filter and delay all packets of all users to and from internet. And this is what a bridge isn't able to do. 10 minutes ago I wrote working code. I will post it soon.

Comment: @stackunderflow you can probably achieve the same result with iptables + netem. But if you want to write your own app, look into `nfqueue`

Answer (score 0):

With socket () you can not chose your network device. This is done with sendto () and recvfrom (). At argument 5 of recvfrom () and sendto () you put a sockaddr struct. There you have a field sockaddr.sll_ifindex where you choose your network card. In my environment 3 for enp3s0 and 4 for enp3s1.

See the cable-emulator code. I testet it 20 minutes and it worked without problems.

```
// network cable emulator

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>

signed long long llmac (unsigned char* pmac)
  {
  signed long long sum= 0;
  signed long long sumd;
  for (signed long lauf= 0; lauf < 6; lauf++)
    {
    sumd= pmac[lauf];
    sum= sum | (sumd << (40 - lauf*8));
    }
  return sum; 
  }

struct macliste
  {
  signed long long anz;
  signed long long mac[100000];
  
  macliste ();
  void add (unsigned char* pmac);
  signed long neu (unsigned char* pmac);
  };

macliste::macliste ()
  {
  anz= 0;
  }

void macliste::add (unsigned char* pmac)
  {
  if (neu (pmac))
    {
    mac[anz]= llmac (pmac);
    anz++;
    }
  }

signed long macliste::neu (unsigned char* pmac)
  {
  signed long long smac;

  smac= llmac (pmac);
  for (signed long lauf= 0; lauf < anz; lauf++)
    if (mac[lauf] == smac)
      return 0;
  return 1;
  }

int main ()
  {
  int sockemp, socksenleft, socksenright;
  signed long result;
  
  unsigned char transferpuffer[10000];

  struct sockaddr_ll sockaddrleft;
  struct sockaddr_ll sockaddrright;
  struct sockaddr_ll sockaddrboth;
  signed long sockaddrsize= sizeof (sockaddrboth);

  char ifnameleft[IFNAMSIZ] = "enp3s0";
  char ifnameright[IFNAMSIZ] = "enp3s1";
  struct ifreq ifindexleft; 
  struct ifreq ifindexright; 
  int indexleft;
  int indexright;
  
  // Socket öffnen
  sockemp= socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
  printf ("sockemp:      %5d\n", sockemp);
  
  // Socket öffnen
  socksenleft= socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
  printf ("socksenleft:  %5d\n", socksenleft);
  
  // Socket öffnen
  socksenright= socket (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
  printf ("socksenright: %5d\n", socksenright);

  printf ("\n");
  
  /* den Index des Interfaces ermitteln */
  printf ("Interfacename left:  %s\n", ifnameleft);
  printf ("Interfacename right: %s\n", ifnameright);
  printf ("\n");
  memset (&ifindexleft, 0, sizeof (struct ifreq));
  memset (&ifindexright, 0, sizeof (struct ifreq));
  strncpy (ifindexleft.ifr_name, ifnameleft, IFNAMSIZ);
  strncpy (ifindexright.ifr_name, ifnameright, IFNAMSIZ);
  result= ioctl (socksenleft, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifindexleft);
  result= ioctl (socksenright, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifindexright);

  indexleft= ifindexleft.ifr_ifindex;
  indexright= ifindexright.ifr_ifindex;
  printf ("interfaceresult: %5ld   indexleft  %5d\n", result, indexleft);
  printf ("interfaceresult: %5ld   indexright %5d\n", result, indexright);

  printf ("\n");

  /* Socketadresse vorbereiten */
  memset (&sockaddrleft, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
  sockaddrleft.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;             /* RAW communication */
  sockaddrleft.sll_hatype   = ARPHRD_ETHER;          /* Ethernet */
  sockaddrleft.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_OTHERHOST;      /* Ziel ist ein anderer Rechner */
  sockaddrleft.sll_ifindex  = indexleft;             /* Interface-Index */
  sockaddrleft.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;              /* Address length*/

  /* Socketadresse vorbereiten */
  memset (&sockaddrright, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
  sockaddrright.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;             /* RAW communication */
  sockaddrright.sll_hatype   = ARPHRD_ETHER;          /* Ethernet */
  sockaddrright.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_OTHERHOST;      /* Ziel ist ein anderer Rechner */
  sockaddrright.sll_ifindex  = indexright;            /* Interface-Index */
  sockaddrright.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;              /* Address length*/

  /* Socketadresse vorbereiten */
  memset (&sockaddrboth, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
  sockaddrboth.sll_family   = PF_PACKET;             /* RAW communication */
  sockaddrboth.sll_hatype   = ARPHRD_ETHER;          /* Ethernet */
  sockaddrboth.sll_pkttype  = PACKET_OTHERHOST;      /* Ziel ist ein anderer Rechner */
  sockaddrboth.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;              /* Address length*/

  // Schnittstellen in den Promiskuitätsmodus schalten
  
  struct ifreq ifr;
  int    raw_socket;
  char   deviceleft[100]= "enp3s0";
  char   deviceright[100]= "enp3s1";
 
  memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (struct ifreq));

// Open A Raw Socket Deviceleft
    if ((raw_socket = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 1)
      {
      printf ("ERROR: Could not open socket, Got #?\n");
      exit (1);
      }

    /* Set the device to use */
    strcpy (ifr.ifr_name, deviceleft);

    /* Get the current flags that the device might have */
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
      {
      perror ("Error: Could not retrive the flags from the device.\n");
      exit (1);
      }

    /* Set the old flags plus the IFF_PROMISC flag */
    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
      {
      perror ("Error: Could not set flag IFF_PROMISC");
      exit (1);
      }
    printf ("Entering promiscuous mode\n");

    /* Configure the device */

    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0)
      {
      perror ("Error: Error getting the device index.\n");
      exit (1);
      }

// Open A Raw Socket Deviceright
    if ((raw_socket = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 1)
      {
      printf ("ERROR: Could not open socket, Got #?\n");
      exit (1);
      }

    /* Set the device to use */
    strcpy (ifr.ifr_name, deviceright);

    /* Get the current flags that the device might have */
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
      {
      perror ("Error: Could not retrive the flags from the device.\n");
      exit (1);
      }

    /* Set the old flags plus the IFF_PROMISC flag */
    ifr.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) == -1)
      {
      perror ("Error: Could not set flag IFF_PROMISC");
      exit (1);
      }
    printf ("Entering promiscuous mode\n");

    /* Configure the device */

    if (ioctl (raw_socket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0)
      {
      perror ("Error: Error getting the device index.\n");
      exit (1);
      }

  // Pakete transferieren
  getchar ();
  signed long packetcounter= 0;
  
  macliste emplisteleft;
  macliste emplisteright;

  while (1)
    {
    result= recvfrom (sockemp, transferpuffer, 10000, 0, (struct sockaddr*) (&sockaddrboth), (socklen_t*)&sockaddrsize);
    if ((sockaddrboth.sll_ifindex != indexleft) && (sockaddrboth.sll_ifindex != indexright))
      continue;
    packetcounter++;
    if ((sockaddrboth.sll_ifindex == indexleft) && (emplisteright.neu (transferpuffer + 6)))
      {
      emplisteleft.add (transferpuffer + 6);   // Ethernet II Paket Quelladresse
      result= sendto (socksenright, transferpuffer, result, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sockaddrright, sizeof (struct sockaddr_ll));
      printf ("sendresult: %5ld %2d\n", result, indexright);
      }
    if ((sockaddrboth.sll_ifindex == indexright) && (emplisteleft.neu (transferpuffer + 6)))
      {
      emplisteright.add (transferpuffer + 6);   // Ethernet II Paket Quelladresse
      result= sendto (socksenleft, transferpuffer, result, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sockaddrleft, sizeof (struct sockaddr_ll));
      printf ("sendresult: %5ld %2d\n", result, indexleft);
      }
    printf ("Packet %10ld  empresult: %5ld %2d %20llx %10lld %10lld\n", packetcounter, result, sockaddrboth.sll_ifindex, llmac (transferpuffer + 6), emplisteleft.anz, emplisteright.anz);
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

compile with gcc 9.3.0 under ubuntu 20.04 server:

g++ transferraw.cc -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic-errors -O2 -o transferraw